# error when converting from RGB to HSV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, hsv

I'm trying to convert an image from RGB to HSV color space, here's a segment of my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils

lower = np.array([0, 48, 80], dtype= "uint8")
upper = np.array([20, 255, 255], dtype= "uint8")

img = cv2.imread('3.JPG', 0)
img = imutils.resize(img, width = 400)
cv2.waitKey(1)

converted = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
new_skinMask = cv2.inRange(converted, lower, upper)
```

but I'm getting an error on:

```
converted = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

the error is:

> OpenCV Error:
>   Assertion failed ((scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth
>   == CV_32F)) in cv::cvtColor

can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Could you post your error as well?

Comment: I edited my question and included the error, thanks for pointing that out :))

Comment: seems like your input failed the assertion. **img** should have 3 or 4 channels. You should check it.

Answer (score 3):

Last parameter in

```
img = cv2.imread('3.JPG', 0)
```

stands for `flags`, and `0` is equal to `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE` (or `IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`). That's why you get the assertion about the number of channels.

If you want to load the image in color either:

- remove this parameter, using default `IMREAD_COLOR` flag, or
- replace it with `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR` (or `IMREAD_COLOR`).

Consider the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#Mat%20imread%28const%20String&%20filename,%20int%20flags%29) for more detail.